# UISwitch on non-retina screen

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiswitch, iphone-3gs

I'm creating a `UISwitch` in `TableViewCell`.

On retina display it looks fine.

But when I'm building a project on 3GS my `UISwitch` looks like a badly painted picture.

http://iwheelbuy.com/stackoverflow/asdf.png

My code

```
{
    ...
    cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"settings model glare", nil);
    UISwitch *cellSwitch = [self switchWithTitle:@"glare"];
    [cellSwitch setCenter:CGPointMake(260.0f, cell.frame.size.height / 2)];
    [cell addSubview:cellSwitch];
    ...
}

- (UISwitch *) switchWithTitle:(NSString *)_title
{
    BOOL switchState;
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:_title] == NO)
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:_title];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
    switchState = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:_title];
    UISwitch *switchForCell = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    if ([_title isEqualToString:@"glare"])
        [switchForCell addTarget:self action:@selector(changedValueForGlare) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    else
        [switchForCell addTarget:self action:@selector(changedValueForShadow) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [switchForCell setOn:switchState];
    return switchForCell;
}
```

Comment: You may want to upload a photo of the problem. Hard to tell what "badly painted picture means".

Comment: I have uploaded an image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, it would be easier in this case to just set the switch as the `accessoryView` of the cell and let it worry about the positioning.

The reason you're seeing a blurry image is that your switch's frame has its origin on a half-pixel. You're setting the `center` of the switch, so where its origin is depends on the size of the switch (which is fixed, because `UISwitch` always uses a system-defined size). So say the switch has a size of 79 x 27 (the standard size), setting the center's y-coordinate to 20 would cause the frame origin's y-coordinate to be at 6.5 (20.0 - 27.0 * 0.5).

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the accessory view issue! That is a great solution

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by a "badly painted picture". Does it look blurry? It might be because its frame is not set to a full point.

What is the height of your cell? The following line may result in the UISwitch being set at 0.5 of a point:

```
[cellSwitch setCenter:CGPointMake(260.0f, cell.frame.size.height / 2)];
```

That's fine on Retina because that's still a full pixel, but on non-Retina it's at 0.5 a pixel (since point = pixel on non-Retina and point = 2 pixels on Retina).

Comment: It most definitely has to do with off-pixels and incorrect frame positioning ;)

Comment: I have tested with half-pixels. Looks better indeed!